# Alternative to d3.ascending(), d3.descending() for sorting undefined values to bottom

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, d3.js

I've got nested array with entries like this assigned to variable `persons`:

```
[
    {
        "person": "test",
        "why": "why test",
        "third": "third entry"
    },
    {
        "person": "test",
        "why": "why test",
        "third": ""
    }
]
```

Normally I would use d3.ascending/descending to sort the array alphabetically.

`persons = persons.sort(function (a,b) { return d3.ascending(a[2], b[2]);});`

However, this isn't suitable for sorting when the array contains `undefined` values. [From the d3.js documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays):

```
Unlike the built-in Math.min, this method ignores undefined values;
```

What is another way I can sort the values? I want to put the `undefined` values at the end of the parent array and the defined values at the top.

Comment: You can supply your own comparison function.

Comment: Something like: `type(a[2]) === 'undefined' < b[2]` ?

Comment: If you only care about definedness, even `a[2] === undefined < b[2] === undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy since you control the comparison function.

This is how D3 implemnets ascending:

```
function ascending(a, b) {
  return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : a >= b ? 0 : NaN;
}
```

So all you need to do is to re-implement it with undefined having proper ordering property:

```
persons = persons.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b[2] == null ? (a[2] == null ? 0 : -1) 
          : b[2] < a[2] ? -1 : b[2] > a[2] ? 1 : b[2] >= a[2] ? 0 : NaN;
});
```

Obviously, you can extract this function to be separate universal comparator.

Descending would be the inverse of it.

Note that in JS `a == null` is true for both, undefined and null.